# how to use dash_html_components.Script command

Tags: plotly-dash

i would like to convert the code below into dash-plotly code.
may i know how to translate the second script tag in the HTML code into dash-plotly?

```css
.summary:hover+.detail,
.detail:hover {
  display: block;
}

.show.detail {
  display: block;
}

.detail {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="summary" href="javascript:void(0);">Sample1</a>
  <div class="detail">Detail of this summary</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="summary" href="javascript:void(0);">Sample2</a>
  <div class="detail">Detail of this summary</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="summary" href="javascript:void(0);">Sample3</a>
  <div class="detail">Detail of this summary</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(".summary").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("show");
  })
</script>
```

Comment: the code is to turn html A tag to become a button to turn on/off the next div tag. hover mouse to the A tag will turn on the display as well.

Answer (score 1):

try to add a custom-file.js in your assets forlder :
https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources
The example with the "altert" works for me, and the script appears in html / body / footer / script when I inspect the page of my app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can build up the same html structure within plotly.
The following code is an working example.

Requirement: Your CSS code must be stored in *static/stylesheet.css*

Example:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from flask import send_from_directory
import os

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

# Configure Samples
sample1 = html.Div([
                dcc.Link('Sample1', href='javascript:void(0);', className='summary'),
                html.Div('Details of this summary', className='detail')
], className='wrapper')

sample2 = html.Div([
                dcc.Link('Sample2', href='javascript:void(0);', className='summary'),
                html.Div('Details of this summary', className='detail')
], className='wrapper')

sample3 = html.Div([
                dcc.Link('Sample3', href='javascript:void(0);', className='summary'),
                html.Div('Details of this summary', className='detail')
], className='wrapper')
# Define layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    sample1,
    sample2,
    sample3
])

app.scripts.append_script({"external_url": [
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
]})

# Add css file (locally hosted)
app.css.append_css({"external_url": [
    "static/stylesheet.css"
]})

# Serving local static files
@app.server.route('/static/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    static_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static')
    return send_from_directory(static_folder, path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```